# New output fields of glm.summary (in R)?

Tags: r, regression

When I do a (logistic) regression in R, I run something like this:

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
mylogit <- glm(a ~ c+d, data = mydata, family="binomial")
summary(mylogit)
```

As of a few months ago, the output for the coefficients might look like this:

```
Call:
glm(formula = a ~ c + d, family = "binomial", data = mydata)
...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.6476     0.1898  -8.680  < 2e-16 ***
c             2.4558     0.3414   7.194 6.29e-13 ***
d             2.3783     0.4466   5.326 1.01e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Trying it today (with a newer version of R), the output looks like the following:

```
Call:
glm(formula = a ~ c + d, family = "binomial", data = mydata)
...
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.6709     0.1924  -8.683  < 2e-16 ***
c1            2.4961     0.3476   7.181 6.94e-13 ***
cc           18.2370   979.6100   0.019    0.985    
d1            2.4524     0.4630   5.296 1.18e-07 ***
dd                NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What do the "c1", "cc", etc fields mean?  I can't seem to find this any documentation, but perhaps I am looking in the wrong places?

Comment: My guess is that the attributes of `mydata` has changed (but not necessarily the actual *values* you see) -- specifically `c` and `d` were numeric variables the first time you ran it and are factors now. Try `is.factor(mydata$c)` to see if it's been made a factor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about possible changes in R code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is anything to do with `glm` at all.

My guess is that the attributes of `mydata$c` and `mydata$d` have changed (but not necessarily the actual values you see) -- specifically it looks like `c` and `d` were numeric variables the first time you ran `glm` and are factors now.

Try `is.factor(mydata$c)` to see if it's been made a factor.

e.g. see these two variables:

```
> mydata$c                                                       #$  -- numeric
 [1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
> mydata2$c                                                      #$  -- factor
 [1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1 2
```

They look the same (apart from the 'levels' bit), but they'll do very different things in a regression ... or a glm.

Comparing attributes:

```
> attributes(mydata$c)
NULL

> attributes(mydata2$c)
    $levels
[1] "0" "1" "2"

$class
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was exactly the problem.  The first line of the file (the non-numeric line that specifies the names of the fields) had accidentally been copied several times in my latest run; removing the extraneous copies let R realize the field was really numeric.